# Formatting my Output Correctly

Tags: java, arrays, format

I'm trying to make my code will display the highest score, lowest score, and average score of a teacher's class.

I want it to display like this:

Highest Score: 94.7, Jake

Lowest Score: 80.2, Emily

Average Score: 85.6

The highest grade and the average grade works, but the lowest grade doesn't. This is what I have so far:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Grades {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> bestStudentPosition = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> worstStudentPosition = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("How many students are in your class? ");
        int totalStudents = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());     
        String[] names = new String[totalStudents];
        double[] scores = new double[totalStudents]; 
        double maxGrade = 0;
        double minGrade = scores[0];
        double avg = 0;
        double sum = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < totalStudents; i++){
              System.out.print("Name: ");
              names[i] = input.next();
              System.out.print("Score: ");
              scores[i] = input.nextDouble();
              sum += scores[i];

              if (scores[i] > maxGrade) {
                  bestStudentPosition.clear(); 
                  maxGrade = scores[i];
                  bestStudentPosition.add(new Integer(i));
              } 
              else if (scores[i] == maxGrade) {
                   bestStudentPosition.add(new Integer(i)); 
              }
              if (scores[i] < minGrade) {
                  worstStudentPosition.clear(); 
                  minGrade = scores[i];
                  worstStudentPosition.add(new Integer(i));
              } 
              else if (scores[i] == minGrade) {  
                   worstStudentPosition.add(new Integer(i)); 
              }

         }

         avg = sum/totalStudents;  
         System.out.print("Highest score: ");
         for (Integer position : bestStudentPosition) { 
             System.out.println(maxGrade + ", " + names[position]);
         }
         System.out.print("Lowest score: ");
         for (Integer position : worstStudentPosition) { 
              System.out.println(minGrade + ", " + names[position]);
         }

         System.out.printf("Average: %3.2f", avg);

    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In if(scores[i]) < minGrade) you have maxGrade variable set instead of minGrade

Comment: `scores[0]` has nothing there. Check the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
scores[i] < minGrade
```

where `minGrade` is 0 initially and you are never assigning it any value other than 0. Also, this will only work if grade will be less than 0.

So, probably what you need to do is,

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Grades {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> bestStudentPosition  = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> worstStudentPosition = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        Scanner            input                = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("How many students are in your class? ");
        int      totalStudents = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
        String[] names         = new String[totalStudents];
        double[] scores        = new double[totalStudents];
        double   maxGrade      = 0;
        double   minGrade      = 0;
        double   avg           = 0;
        double   sum           = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < totalStudents; i++) {
            System.out.print("Name: ");
            names[i] = input.next();
            System.out.print("Score: ");
            scores[i] = input.nextDouble();
            sum += scores[i];
            if (i == 0) {
                minGrade = scores[0];
            }
            if (scores[i] > maxGrade) {
                bestStudentPosition.clear();
                maxGrade = scores[i];
                bestStudentPosition.add(new Integer(i));
            } else if (scores[i] == maxGrade) {
                bestStudentPosition.add(new Integer(i));
            }
            if (i > 0 && scores[i] < minGrade) {
                worstStudentPosition.clear();
                minGrade = scores[i];
                worstStudentPosition.add(new Integer(i));
            } else if (scores[i] == minGrade) {
                worstStudentPosition.add(new Integer(i));
            }

        }

        avg = sum / totalStudents;
        System.out.print("Highest score: ");
        for (Integer position : bestStudentPosition) {
            System.out.println(maxGrade + ", " + names[position]);
        }
        System.out.print("Lowest score: ");
        for (Integer position : worstStudentPosition) {
            System.out.println(minGrade + ", " + names[position]);
        }

        System.out.printf("Average: %3.2f", avg);

    }
}
```

assign `minGrade` with initial value of `scores[0]` before these conditions. e.g.

`minGrade = scores[0];`

This is the output:

> How many students are in your class? 3
>
> Name: Harry
>
> Score: 90.2
>
> Name: Laurent
>
> Score: 99.99
>
> Name: Darren
>
> Score: 98.9
>
> Highest score: 99.99, Laurent
>
> Lowest score: 90.2, Harry
>
> Average: 96.36

Comment: Is this what you were referring to?(I edited the code)

Comment: Updated the answer @JamesV.

Comment: When I run this, it puts the highest grade and average grade (which is also incorrect) prematurely. So I'm not sure what's wrong with it.

Comment: This is what it does:                                                                             How many students are in your class? 3
Name: James
Score: 92.4
Lowest score: 92.4, James
Average: 0.00Name:

Comment: Thank you, I was missing a few things.